# Retina graphics for Ask Different?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, graphics

As retina displays are [becoming](http://www.apple.com/iphone/) [more](http://www.apple.com/ipad/) [pervasive](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/) in Apple hardware, and we're here to support users of Apple products, I think it would be great if the AD site included retina versions of its image resources, such as the **header image**, **voting buttons**, and **user profile photos**.

[This WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=602) has info about how to achieve this. There are several choices for detecting retina displays, including CSS `@media` queries and `window.devicePixelRatio`.

This might give you an idea of how it looks *without* retina graphics:

[image: retina screenshot]

(Only slightly relevant but fun: [AD logo I made with pure CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/fy7Fn/).)

Comment: Apparently I don't have Myriad Pro on my system. So the logo doesn't quite look the same. Otherwise, neat.

Comment: @JasonSalaz the logo should be the same for you, since it's just an image.

Comment: @Jin he's referring to the CSS logo linked at the bottom of my post (which depends on the Myriad Pro font).

Comment: @jtbandes ah ok. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with the [design update](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/site-design-update).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

We have plans to update all the icons for SE sites to retina at some point. It will be a lengthy process. We're still deciding on which icons have higher priority. The obvious ones are the logo and voting arrows/favstar.

Comment: Could Ask Different act as a testbed for these changes? It would be only appropriate :)

Comment: It certainly would make the most sense for AD to get them first :)

Comment: Do voting buttons even have to be images? Maybe on other sites but not on this one. There are characters that match the buttons and can be manipulated with CSS color, gradient, and shadow properties. ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼ ◀ ► ◀ ► you know the rest.

I suppose for consistency's sake you would need them all to be images, or all to be characters, though.

Comment: If you look at the html structure, each arrow is a single anchor. also, we can't use ▲/▼ as the anchor text due to screen reader issues.

Comment: Using unicode symbols tends to cause issues of rendering different on different systems, depending on the font substitution.

Comment: @Jin any update on the work towards updating the images for SE sites?

Comment: Now that I'm using the site on a retina MBP, I really, really, really am a huge fan of the work being done incrementally. The controls that get used hundreds of times and the thin lines being drawn on review panes, mod tools and such are gorgeous. I appreciate the structural work being done even though not all icons are 2x yet.